# How to add files to be committed in a faster way?

Tags: git

For example, this is the status of a branch in my local repository:

```
14:56:15 /srv/www/gamersmafia/current[max-decisiones]$ git status
# On branch max-decisiones
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   app/controllers/respuestas_controller.rb
#       modified:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb
#       modified:   app/models/decision.rb
#       modified:   app/models/gm_portal.rb
#       modified:   app/models/term.rb
#       modified:   app/views/respuestas/index.html.erb
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       app/assets/stylesheets/old/sprites/games_sprites.css
#
```

If I want to add files to commit them, I have to **write the path to the file, or select and paste it** after writing `git add`.

Is there a faster way to work with git selecting files to add, checkout, etc? For example, **if I just want to add 2 files for commit**?

Comment: `git add` is recursive..!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could just add them (also the newly created files) with:

```
git add -A .
```

And then commit.
If you want to just add some of them you can use add interactively:

```
git add -i
```

`git` will ask for what files you want to add. If you're using linux or a mac you can create an alias in your shell to make the command shorter and so even faster.

Another solution is to use a wrapper for your editor/IDE. You can find a wrapper for almost any developing tool (from eclipse to VIM). This wrappers usually let you perform some actions quickly, just like `add` or `commit` the file your editing. You can file a complete list in the [git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools).

Comment: Wow, `git add -i` is very impressive! I'll wait a bit before selecting an answer, but I can't imagine something better than it :)

Comment: I can :) Git wrappers are better imho. You can add/unadd  a file, open them up quickly to check added lines, plus dozens of other features you usually want to do along with `git status`. And when using vim, you feel like you never leaved your console!

Comment: I've just started using `git add --interactive` (didn't know it existed) and works well. This tutorial from the book Pro Git (available for free at the docs) has helped me to learn how to use it: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging

Answer (score 2):

To add everything, both tracked and untracked files. Add a dot after add. For example:

```
git add .
```

If you just wanted to commit the files that are already tracked without adding new ones, you can use the "-a" flag for git commit. Like:

```
git commit -a
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the most important thing. Also wanted to ask, how could do it quickly if I just want to add 2 files (for example) to commit, and I have 9 not staged for commit. I edited the question :/

Comment: For selective addition, you can either use [command-line tab completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) or the "-i" interactive mode that @Atropo pointed out. (I use tab completion personally.)